# codesign: unrecognized option `--entitlements'

Tags: iphone, codesign

I get this codesign error when i build the application

```
codesign: unrecognized option `--entitlements'

Usage: codesign -s identity [-fv*] [-o flags] [-r reqs] [-i ident] path ... # sign
       codesign -v [-v*] [-R testreq] path|pid ... # verify
       codesign -d [options] path ... # display contents
       codesign -h pid ... # display hosting paths
       codesign: unrecognized option `--entitlements'
Usage: codesign -s identity [-fv*] [-o flags] [-r reqs] [-i ident] path ... # sign

Build failed (1 error)
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to the latest xcode version and updated the latest updates for mac leopard.
and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen that one before but it suggests that something is broken in your Xcode installation.  If `codesign` doesn't know about the `-entitlements` option, it's either an old version or maybe one that didn't come from the iPhone SDK.  This might happen if, for example, you've recently installed an older copy of the developer tools.  It might happen for other reasons-- never having seen it before I can't be completely sure.

You could investigate the problem by using `xcode-select` at the command line.  Something like this:

```
% xcode-select -print-path
/Developer
```

It prints the path to the current version of Xcode used by command-line tools (like `codesign`) and it should point toward your copy of the iPhone SDK.  If it doesn't, you can change it via `xcode-select -switch /path/to/SDK'`.

It may be easier to just reinstall the iPhone SDK, though if it was me I'd want to investigate it and understand what went wrong.

Comment: The command should be `codesign --display --entitlements - <App File Path>`. Don't miss the "-" after "--entitlements"

Comment: I wasted an hour for this `-`. They should have highlighted that fact in the documentation