# Device Token didn't receive

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I'm getting this alert message while getting device token by using this code.

> "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomainCode=3000"no valid
>   aps-environment'entitlement string found for application"
>   Userinfo=0x1665f5b0 {NSlocalizedDescription=no valid
>   'app-environment'entitlement string found for application}

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)var_deviceToken
{

    NSString *tokenString = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    NSLog(@"Push Notification tokenstring is %@",tokenString);
    self.deviceToken = tokenString;


 }

 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
 {

     NSString* s=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",error];
     UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Device Token didn't recieve" message:s delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [alert show];

 }
```

Comment: Did you enable push notification for you app in the provisioning profile?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" in Xcode 4.3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987102/how-to-fix-no-valid-aps-environment-entitlement-string-found-for-application)

Answer (score 1):

The reasons for getting this issue is ,

1. You didn't enable the push notification in your provisional profile .
2. If enabled ,you may forget of using that bundle identifier and mobile provision .

Comment: This solution is correct. Actually for checking device token with AMazon SNS sample app, i had to finally change the sample app's bundle identifier and run it using the push enabled provisioning profile.