# worklight Push Notification not working in IOS Sandbox mode

Tags: ios, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

For Android Push notificaion working fine.
But for IOS device after creating sanbox certificte and all process, eventhough the push notification not working. Even it's not connecting with server too.

Whenever loading for IOS, I am getting this error below:

```
FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found
```

**Error image:**
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYq27.jpg

Answer (score 0):

That's a strange error...

Make sure that you have:

1. Placed the .p12 certificate in the **application** folder
2. Used the correct name for the certificate: "apns-certificate-sandbox.p12" (for development) or "apns-certificate-production.p12" (for production)
3. Used the correct password in the pushSender element

After logging-in to the application, you should get an alert stating that you are able to subscribe.

To make sure you have properly setup your iOS development environment (App ID, certificate, provisioning, etc...) follow this guide: [Understanding and setting up artifacts required to use iOS devices and Apple Push Notifications services (APNS) in development environment](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/understanding-and-setting-up-push-notifications-in-development-evnironment?lang=en).

Make sure that you build the application (Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server) to ensure that the certificate gets deployed to the server.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of couple of reasons, but most common is if provisioning profile was created before APNS certificate. You need to re-generate provisioning profile after creating APNS, login to your account on XCode and refresh provisioning profiles.

Also read following:

[How to fix “no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987102/how-to-fix-no-valid-aps-environment-entitlement-string-found-for-application)

Cheers !!