# Push Notifications not received if Xcode Server signs with iOS Team provisioning profile

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, codesign, xcode-server

I recently implemented in an app Push Notifications. We also use an instance of Xcode Server to make automated builds for our QA.
When I updated the app id to support push notifications, I regenerated the provisioning profiles for both development and production.
I also enforced in the build settings to use the regenerated Dev prov. profile for debug builds and the Prod prov. profile for release builds.

But after this, the server didn't succeed to sign the archive anymore because for some reason, the server automatically creates a Team provisioning profile. I tried to force it somehow. I also tried to move prov. profiles in the folder where the server stores them. I also tried exporting/importing private keys. No success. I changed the build settings and went back to "automatic" rather than forcing a provisioning profile.

When I install a build from my local machine it signs with the manual prov. profile. And push notifications work.
If I install a build made with the server, it doesn't work. In the console here's the message:

> SpringBoard[53] : No valid 'aps-environment' entitlement
>   string found for application 'myApp': (null). Notifications will not
>   be delivered.

When I take a look in the Apple Developer account, the provisioning profile used by the server says that IT HAS push notifications enabled. I can't edit it because it's managed by Xcode.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you updated also on server side the Certs? Looks like  "current Provisioning Profile does not contain APNS information, as the Provisioning Profile is created BEFORE creating the APNS certificate." see here [No valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application on app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324020/no-valid-aps-environment-entitlement-string-found-for-application-on-app-store)

Comment: I also deleted the provisioning profile from the Developer account and also from the folder in which the server stores them. Reconnected team account. Restarted server. Same issue.

Comment: Simple question. After closing XCode, on restarting it, did you manage to go to XCode (menu)/Preferences/Accounts -> your account ->View Details refresh (the clockwise arrow button? at the bottom)? This after you downloaded new certs and double clicked them...

Comment: Are we talking about Xcode server? Xcode server has it's own set of certificates, provisioning profiles, cache, derived data, etc.

Comment: Not sure, I am not at home to test XCode server signing issues, but I remember to add Entitlements.plist in order to APNS via XCode server distrib.app.