# with Xcode 8 no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found

Tags: xcode

I installed Xcode 8. Since then I am getting

> application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:, Thread
>   [{number = 1, name = main}] error [Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment'
>   entitlement string found for application"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment'
>   entitlement string found for application}]

I tried downloading and double-clicking provisioning files again. It did not work.

I did check that push notifications are enabled for provisioning files.

I even logged out of Xcode account and logged in again...did not help.

Which setting I might be missing for Xcode8/ios10?

It was working for Xcode 7.3/ios9/8.

Please help.

Comment: ok...I had to explicitly enable push notifications in capabilities tab

Comment: Duplicate post, I found my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324020/no-valid-aps-environment-entitlement-string-found-for-application-on-app-store

Answer (score 38):

Please enable the push notification toggle , make it ON, in the capabilities section (Next to project section)

Comment: just toggling the switch few times fixes the problem !

Comment: Man, you saved my life. Thanks.

Comment: Man, I remember turning it on before migrating to Xcode 8... thanks for this man.

Answer (score 1):

One more thing...
Check that you enable Push notifications for PROPER configuration.
I've wasted around an hour trying to figure out what's going on with pushes on DEBUG with permanent NO APS entitlement. But pushes was enabled ONLY in RELEASE.