# no valid ‘aps-environment’ entitlement string found for application - Appcelerator

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, apple-push-notifications, appcelerator

I have an existing App framework which I use on many different clients.

I am setting it up for an updated customer and testing the Push Notifications, however although I am able to create an ArrowDB user I am unable to register for Push notifications with the error message:

no valid ‘aps-environment’ entitlement string found for application

I am using Xcode 8.1, iOS 10.0 on the test iPhone and Appcelerator Studio, build: 4.8.0.201611121409 and idk 5.5.1.v20160921190109

The certificates are all correct and I have recreated them just in case to check if there was an issue.

I have read many of the other threads here and they all relate to Xcode but nothing that seems to help my case.

I'm tearing my hair out!

One other aside is the Facebook module is playing up and I get the error:

canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)

My only thought is that something is wrong in the trap.xml file? but no errors are coming up and everything else int he app works perfectly

any ideas?

Comment: Refer to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39594073/post-ios10-xcode-8-0-missing-push-notification-entitlement-error-after-build

Comment: thanks Fahad86, that now leaves the error message: push notification certificate not configured any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I recalled reading this Jira ticket a while back. Perhaps it will be of help. https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23908

Answer (score 0):

here is the thing: We changed the entitlements-handling in Ti.Facebook so it allows the `keychain-access` key to be to set. But as this will collide with your push-entitlements, you may need to write those in your entitlements file as well, e.g.

```
<key>aps-environment</key>
<string>development</string>
```

The change also was that Xcode 8 handles provisioning profiles differently, so the old way did not work again. However, in 6.0.1, we will improve the whole capabilities handling by injecting the required capabilities per feature / module dynamically, so you won't need a custom capabilities file anymore. See [MOD-2313](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/MOD-2313) and it's linked tickets for more infos on that.

Related problems (natively, regarding push-capabilities):

- [Xcode 8 APS Environment Entitlement won't set to production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39625258/xcode-8-aps-environment-entitlement-wont-set-to-production)
- [with Xcode 8 no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713154/with-xcode-8-no-valid-aps-environment-entitlement-string-found)

Let us know if you have further questions!

Comment: Hi Hans, thank you for the response. I have a few questions. by entitlement file what do you mean? is this the tiap.xml file? and the Xcode issue for the aps issue I'm building in Appcelerator so where do I change the capabilities to enable the push notifications?

Answer (score 0):

checked if your push certs are configured correctly over here: https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/, and that the provisioning profile you are using to build is one WITHOUT wildcard characters?

Comment: thanks - yes all the certificates are valid and I went through the process of reissuing them and the profile is for the specific app