# Why "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken" is not getting called n swift 3, iOS 10, XCode 8?

Tags: swift3, xcode8, ios10

My app has :

APP ID - push-notification enabled,
Provision Profile (Development) - push-notification enabled,
Target - capabilities - push-notification enabled,
Target - background mode - background fetch, remote notification enabled

In Appdelegate
1.`import UserNotifications`

2.`class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`

```
3. 

     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *)
            {
                let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
                center.delegate = self
                center.requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .sound, .alert], completionHandler: { (granted, error) in
                    if error == nil
                    {


                        //UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("\(error?.localizedDescription)")

                    }
                })
            }
            else
            {
                registerForPushNotifications(application)
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
    }
```

but `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is not get called instead `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` is getting call

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
```

Following error I'm getting at `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError`

> Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}

Is I am missing something?

Comment: Add error that you are getting in `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError`.

Comment: @NiravD I have updated my question, is there anything missing in my implementation?

Comment: Check out this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324020/no-valid-aps-environment-entitlement-string-found-for-application-on-app-store and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987102/how-to-fix-no-valid-aps-environment-entitlement-string-found-for-application

Answer (score 1):

I am also face the same issue in `Xcode 8` and I had resolved the issue by
select the option in `Capabilities->Push Notification->Add the Push Notifications entitlement to your entitlements file`.

For more information please find the below screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

And once you select the option then a entitlement file added to your project folder. Please find the below screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

As `XCode 8`, the entitlements are set from your local entitlements file rather than from the provisioning profile you created on the Apple Developer Portal. The entitlements will now need to be added to your Xcode build under Capabilities in addition to in your provisioning profile.

Hope it works for you!!!

Comment: YES. I have already enabled entitlements. I enabled this and after that entitlement file is created. is I am missing something?

Comment: Then I thought there is a problem in provisioning profile please review it because I did not find any issues other than that.

Comment: In provosioning profile pushnotification is enabled, even for iOS 9 I am getting notification with same provision profile but not with iOS 10...is this possible if provision profile is not correct?

Comment: Then please review the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532953/push-notifications-not-being-received-on-ios-10-but-working-on-ios-9-and-before which help you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran to similar kind of problem when I update to latest version of XCode and Sierra.

- I got this fixed after add the Apple ID related to that project under 
  Project -> Preference as follow, Try it.
- I also performed all the steps you have followed for supporting iOS 10.

[image]