# Failed registering for push notifications iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

I want add push notification for `iOS` app. I'm using [this tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_setting_up_push_notification_iOS.html)

When run from xcode to Device (direct). Its success But, when I upload to testFlight. I get an error.

> Failed registering for push notifications.The application will not be able to receive notifications.Error in registration for Push notification,check your provisioning profile.Original error:no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application

[image]

Comment: Seems like you haven't enabled push notification in provisioning profile.

Comment: yes, But in App IDs (apple developer). I am already enable push notification for development and production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be your Provisioning profile/entitlements file doesn't contains `aps-environment` key.

Delete the existing provisioning profile from your xcode and re-download it from your appledeveloper account and make sure you have `aps-environment` key pair in your app's .entitlements file before uploading to test flight.

Comment: yes, i try and solve the problem, the first one is create provisioning profile as iOS Distribution (before:iOS Development) , second: add aps-environment : production in entitlements. Thanks Vittal Pai

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of modes that you have to taken care of: Production and Distribution. Set it accordingly.

BTW try it:
Go to Xcode "Preferences"

Select tab named "Accounts"

Select Apple ID and click "View Details"

Click on the arrow on the bottom left corner to refresh

Click "Done"

And try again !

For more details follow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324020/no-valid-aps-environment-entitlement-string-found-for-application-on-app-store).

Comment: I am already test this solution, But the popup error appear , always

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue after publishing to test flight. I tried lot of time. later, i recreated distribution profile and signing with new distribution profile solve that issue. Now, I am able to register my device to push notification.