# Failed to get token, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application"

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

Been Stuck on this one issue for quite a while now. Trying to run the following line:

```
[application registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

and getting the error

```
(via: - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
})

2015-04-03 16:06:42.753 TownHall[696:169453] Failed to get token, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x17426a1c0 {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}

Tried some of the stuff with the following associated post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987102/how-to-fix-no-valid-aps-environment-entitlement-string-found-for-application but little luck.
```

This includes: 
1) Recreating a provisioning profile
2) Recreating ID and checking that it matches and has push enabled
3) Clean and rebuild, etc
4) Creating of new certificates
5) Refresh with Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > View Details (Select your account)

Wondering if anyone has any solutions for this?

Happy to share any other information that people might find useful for solving this problem.

Thanks a lot in advance for help!

Comment: Post error message please

Comment: Added more info above if it helps. The error message is just the title...

Comment: if there's entitlement in build settings, could you try to delete it? another possible reason, you can use iphone configuration utility to delete all provision except the latest one

Comment: where do I find entitlement?

Comment: It is in build settings/code signing section, but if you project doesn't use entitlements file, then I can guess provision issue?

Answer (score 22):

Go to your projects Target under `Capabilities` section, you'll find this error glowing. XCode may suggest to fix it for you automatically.[image]

You'll have to create a two entitlements(AppName_Debug.entitlements and AppName_Release.entitlements) file within your project with the following content:
AppName_Debug.entitlements

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
 <plist version="1.0">
      <dict>
        <key>aps-environment</key>
          <string>development</string>
      </dict>
</plist>
```

AppName_Release.entitlements

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
 <plist version="1.0">
      <dict>
        <key>aps-environment</key>
          <string>production</string>
      </dict>
</plist>
```

Add these two files under Code Signing Entitlments in Build Settings under appropriate option.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a valid provisioning profile or team is none

Comment: How do I check whether the provisioning profile is valid or not?

Comment: the .p12 file associated to your profile is not valid check it on the keychain

Answer (score 0):

IF you see the error 'entitlement string not found for application', add the aps-environment and development key value pair in the entitlements file like stated above