# Unable to Register for Push (Xcode 8)

Tags: swift3, xcode8

After swift 3.0 migration and compiling the app with Xcode 8, start seeing this pop up dialog after running app on device.

[image]

How do we fix this?

Might be related to iOS 10. Tested with a iOS 9 device and don't see this pop up .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" in Xcode 4.3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987102/how-to-fix-no-valid-aps-environment-entitlement-string-found-for-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an settings in Xcode 8 that you have to turn it on:

[image]

Credit goes to DipakSonara's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39615693/1035008)